# Fermat primality test for big primes

Tags: c, linux, primes, gmp

I’m currently trying to implement RSA encryption algorithm for a school project. And after looking into it I thought that generating my own prime numbers would be interesting too. I’m using the gmp lib to store the numbers.

A few sources said that this is generally done by using a sieving method and then doing probabilistic test on the numbers, in my case I’m starting with the Fermat test:

a^(potPrime-1) ≡ 1 (mod potPrime)

The problem I’m having is calculating “a^(potPrime-1)”, I couldn’t find a function in the gmp lib that can calculate an mpz_t power another mpz_t so I wrote my own which is really a while that keeps looping until I’ve multiplied the number by itself the desired amount of times.
This works with small numbers, but when potPrime can go up to 2^2048 this solution isn’t adequate.

Does anyone know how I could get around this? Here’s the code for the Fermat test:

```
int fermatTest(mpz_t potPrime, mpz_t a) //The fermat test is a mathimatical test that will determine if a number is potentialy prime.
{                                       //a is a random number between ]1;p-1[
    int result;
    mpz_t potPrimeMin1,aSqPotPrimeMin1,val1; //decalre mpz type value, val1=1
    mpz_init(potPrimeMin1); //initialises the mpz type value of the number containing potPrime minus 1
    mpz_init(aSqPotPrimeMin1);//value of a^(p-1)
    mpz_init(val1); //a mpz type var where val1 is allways 1
    mpz_set_ui(val1,1);

    mpz_sub_ui(potPrimeMin1,potPrime,1); //subtracts 1 from potPrime and stores it in potPrimeMin1

    mympz_pow(aSqPotPrimeMin1,a,potPrimeMin1);//aSqPotPrimeMin1=a^potPrimeMin1

    result = mpz_congruent_p(aSqPotPrimeMin1,val1,potPrime); //test checks if a^(potPrime-1) ≡ 1 (mod potPrime) - returns non zero if congruent

    //returns non zero if operation is true, 0 if not

    mpz_clear(potPrimeMin1);//frees the variables used
    mpz_clear(aSqPotPrimeMin1);
    mpz_clear(val1);

    return result;
}
```

and this is the code for the pow function:

```
int mympz_pow(mpz_t result, mpz_t base, mpz_t power)
{
    mpz_t i;
    mpz_init(i);
    mpz_set_ui(i,1);
    mpz_set(result,base);
    //mpzPrint("1",result);
    while(mpz_cmp(i,power) < 0)
    {
        mpz_mul(result,result,base);
        //mpzPrint("2",result);
        mpz_add_ui(i,i,1);
        mpzPrint("pow",power);
        mpzPrint("i",i);
    }
    //mpzPrint("3",result);
    mpz_clear(i);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html#Integer-Exponentiation ?

Comment: if you *have* to do it yourself, you should use repeated squaring instead of repeatedly multiplying.

Comment: For computing `pow`, note that 2^(2k) = 2^k * 2^k.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it

Comment: If you are interested in some more algorithmic input have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: There are two functions , `mpz_pow_ui` and `mpz_ui_pow_ui` that do what `mympz_pow` is doing, only much much faster.  They are explained in detail in section `5.7 Exponentiation Functions` of the `gmp` library.  I would suggest you read the documentation very thoroughly if you are going to be completing a project as many of the things you think you may need to roll out on your own are already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmp has a function `mpz_powm` that does modular exponentiation. If you want to do it yourself, use the square-and-multiply algorithm:

```
function powerMod(b, e, m)
    x := 1
    while e > 0
        if e%2 == 1
            x, e := (x*b)%m, e-1
        else b, e := (b*b)%m, e//2
    return x
```

This takes time logarithmic in the exponent rather than linear, as your algorithm does. Or you may prefer to use the `mpz_probab_prime_p` and let gmp do all the work for you.